# How can I make TypeScript convert an object type to become a function's parameter type?

Tags: typescript

I have an object looks like this

```js
type PersonObject = {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
};
```

I want to convert `PersonObject` type to this type

```js
type PersonFunction = (firstName: string, lastName: string) => void;
```

I'm stuck at the converter part

```js
type Converter<T> = ?
```

So the usage become

```js
type PersonFunction = Converter<PersonObject>;
```

I've tried [utility-types](https://github.com/piotrwitek/utility-types), but it doesn't have the utility I want.

How can I write that converter?

Comment: Nope, object type to tuple type  (what we could spread to become parameter types) is not supported

Comment: If you think more logically. What you want is `{a: string, b: number}` to `(a: string, b: number) => void`, but `{b: number, a: string}` is the same thing as other object, but `(b: number, a: string) => void` is not the same as other function.